# ASP.NET Web API method model null

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

So, first of all I best explain that I am calling this method via AngularJS. I have many other controllers, but what makes this one unique is that the model only has one property:

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And so my controller method (which is very simple) just looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create(Subscriber model)
{

    // Try to find the subscriber
    var subscriber = await this.service.GetAsync(model.Email);

    // If the subscriber does not exist
    if (subscriber != null) {

        // Create the subscriber
        this.service.Create(model);

        // Save the datbase changes
        await this.unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

I didn't create a RequestModel although I might just do that to stop my method being invoked when the model is null.

So, the issue is just that, the model is always null.
I have my AngularJS service which looks like this:

```
.service('SubscriberService', ['Api', function (api) {
    var apiUrl = 'api/subscribers';

    // Subscribe
    this.subscribe = function (email) {

        // Create our model
        var model = {
            email: email
        };

        console.log(model);

        // Create our subscriber
        return $http.post(apiUrl, model);
    };
}])
```

in that, the console log shows the model with the email value. 
In my web config I have this line:

```
serializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

which handles the camel case, although I have also tried with Pascal case to no avail.

Does anyone know why it isn't working? I have spent too much time staring at it.

Comment: Did you inspect if the call to the action is actually made? The rout is correct?

Comment: Sholdn't url be 'api/subscribers/create'?

Comment: This code looks fine. It should work. Model binding does not care about casing.Both PascalCasing and camelCasing will work as long as the property names match.

Comment: yeah I used fiddler, I can see that the model is being posted. I put a breakpoint on the actual method and it hits it, just that there is no model....

Comment: @vidalsasoon has the correct answer below. You need to serialize your js model to json and you need to add the [FromBody] attribute to your method signature.

Comment: why would I have to do that when I don't do it on any other controller in my application? Also, it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am fairly certain that this won't help anyone else, but the issue was with the controller itself. I had copied it from one of my other controllers because the methods in it were nearly the same and one thing that I copied along with it was the **Authorize** annotation.
I am using code first EF and I had just deleted my database and recreated it, but the angularJS still had a token for me so figured I was authenticated and the new controller allowed me to get into it but didn't return a 401 error because nothing was getting passed to it.

Anyway, removing **Authrozie** from the controller fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your second block of code you are using the following:

```
return Ok();
```

By doing so you are only answering your api call with an empty HTTP 200 response. You should be answering with the model loaded from the database.

I'd suggest trying:

```
return Ok(subscriber);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to return an empty 200 response, it's a subscriber method, so nothing should be returned apart from the status code.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this: "[FromBody]"

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Create([FromBody]Subscriber model)
```

Also worth trying is:

```
return $http.post(apiUrl, angular.toJson(model));
```

Comment: Hi, neither of these worked. I don't do this anywhere else in my project so I would have been surprised if it had of :o I am starting the think that I am doing something stupid somewhere but can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried stringifying your model so it can be serialized as json in your api method?

```
return $http.post(apiUrl, JSON.stringify(model));
```